# Application's user data is 20 MB without storing anything react-native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

I've developed an application in react-native and published the .aab file to Play Store. Download size is almost 11 MB. After installation it takes 57 MB. [Screenshot is attached of details of storage consumed by the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40hNv.jpg) And following is the dependencies of the application.

```
{
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
        "jssha": "^3.2.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-native": "^0.64.0",
        "react-native-camera": "^3.43.4",
        "react-native-config": "^1.4.2",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
        "react-native-polyfill": "^1.2.1",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
        "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
        "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
        "react-refresh": "^0.9.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
    }
```

I need to know why user data is taking 20 MB?

Nothing is being stored initially in the application just some empty tables are being stored initially in the database. Just some db tables are being created.

Thanks

Comment: Ahead of time compilation?

Comment: Can you please explain and provide references for it? Thanks

Comment: No. That's pretty basic Android stuff.

Comment: Even we are facing the same issue, are you able to fix it @HamadSafdar ?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually normal for an app to be larger than the downloaded size. You can think application bundles as compressed files. Once they are downloaded, they are also getting installed and when that happens, app size grows. There are multiple ways of reducing the size of an app, but in any case it will always become larger when it is installed than it is stated in the stores.

Comment: Yes I understand that. The thing is that I am not storing any large data in sqlite or any other storage but as you can see in SS, user data is consuming 20.77 mb, which is I think not normal, and need assistance to reduce or at least analyze that what is taking this much space?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, I don't know how to analyze user data itself. But what I can say that, when I examine my prod RN applications, even though they don't hold or save any additional local data, user data of them also becomes 20-30 mb immediately after the initial launch.

Comment: Maybe it is one of the caveats of using react-native but still need to confirm it.

Comment: Any new findings here? I'm facing the same issue.

By checking the folder structure on a rooted device I realised that the system copies all the native code (.so libs) from the react-native app to user data folder upon startup. This is not the case for native Android applications. The reason why it's done is still unclear to me.